# What are some ways to parse binary data with a repeating structure?

Tags: c++, parsing, binaryfiles, ifstream

I have written some output files which have a large number of data sets of identical format. For example, 10,000 sets of 200 doubles. I used the write command:

loop over 10000 (# sets)
loop over 200 (size of each set)
and did this:

```
outputfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&onedouble),sizeof(onedouble));
```

I don't have a sense of the easiest ways to read this type of data. I need to look at each individual set one at a time. I have read that generally reading binary data is done all at once into a large block of memory, but I'm not sure how to parse it after that. What are some ways to do that?

Is it significantly slower to read one set of data at a time from the binary file? I have not seen any examples of that type of input.

Comment: You could read the file, `reinterpret_cast` to a pointer of the appropriate type, and read it as an array.

Comment: Do the ifstream "open" commands work the same for binary files? It's not clear to me how to set the pointer to the right location.

Comment: *"What are some ways to do that"* => Too broad a question.  But note if you forego iostream-style serialization and start trying to write the raw memory of your types and structures to files, you will wind up creating files specific to your compiler and platform (endianness, sizes, etc).  There are libraries like [Boost::Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) to help with that.